# How to find a document path from form method as download

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Site [URL](https://bids.hctx.net/bso/external/bidDetail.sdo?bidId=17%2F0244&parentUrl=activeBids)

Target: To know about document path

Scripting: Jscript to post form.

```
javascript:downloadFile('12767');

  function downloadFile(fileNbr, itemNbr) {
    document.forms[0].action = "/bso/external/bidDetail.sdo";
    document.forms[0].downloadFileNbr.value=fileNbr;
    document.forms[0].itemNbr.value=itemNbr;
    document.forms[0].mode.value="download";
    document.forms[0].submit();
  }
```

Objective is to scrap the actual path of the document.

Comment: you mean `document.location`? It's got the `protocol`, `host`, `origin` and so on.

Comment: Yes, the location of the document is hidden or used in a way to hide. I wish to have actual location instead of downloading document.

Comment: how about `document.forms[0].baseURI` ?

Comment: I tried but it does not resolve my concern
Result: https://bids.hctx.net/bso/index.jsp

Comment: why? you could parse the `host`, `protocol`, etc. from the whole `baseURI`

Comment: what if you try `document.location.toString()` ?

Comment: That was resulted in site url itself.
Request URL:https://bids.hctx.net/bso/external/bidDetail.sdo
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:74.124.60.227:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: document.forms[0].baseURI
[link](https://bids.hctx.net/bso/index.jsp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you'll get is by making a download request on the page, and then watching the network tab in your browser to see the download request URL and it contents. e.g. for the "17/0244 Attachment" link in that page you gave, then the URL used to download (generated by the downloadFile JS method submitting the form) is

```
https://bids.hctx.net/bso/external/bidDetail.sdo?bidId=17%2F0244&parentUrl=activeBids
```

Since it's a POST request there is also quite a lot of data in the request body itself, which are parameters the server needs in order to return the correct document. In the case of the request I made they were:

```
mode:download
bidId:17/0244
docId:17/0244
currentPage:1
querySql:
downloadFileNbr:12767
itemNbr:undefined
parentUrl:activeBids
fromQuote:
```

It appears that this request must call a server-side script, which then (presumably) retrieves the document from some repository and offers it for download.  The actual file itself need not be held in a location directly accessible by a URL, and indeed almost certainly isn't. e.g. it could be held in a database as a binary field, or in some backend SAN storage, or a document management system such as FileNet or similar.

So if you want to create a direct link to the document yourself, the best you will be able to do is come up with some code or static HTML form which makes an identical POST request to that URL, with identical querystring and body params. There is no direct link to the static document itself.

Comment: I tried with below code but not luck too. The solution which I'm thinking now is downloading on local, uploading to remote repository and make it available.
var targetForm = $(document.forms[0]);
var urlWithParams = targetForm.attr('action') + "?" + targetForm.serialize();
(urlWithParams)

Comment: Sorry but I've no idea how that code you've shown is connected to my explanation. does it include the correct parameters? We'll need to see a proper complete example to see if you did it right or not. Also it sounds like you are planning to take the content from the original server and host it on your own server? Firstly that sounds legally dubious, and secondly how are you going to keep it up to date if the original page changes?

Comment: Aside from all that, the question was "how can I know the document path". I've explained that, which I think answers the question adequately. You can't scrape it from the page directly without parsing both the HTML and the JavaScript. I don't think the makers of the site intended you to hotlink to their documents. And I doubt they will be very happy if they discover you hosting your own copies somewhere else. I certainly wouldn't be.

Comment: That code of mine reflected below result
https://bids.hctx.net/bso/seller/bidDetail.sdo?mode=&bidId=17%2F0028&docId=17%2F0028&currentPage=1&querySql=&downloadFileNbr=0&itemNbr=0&parentUrl=&fromQuote=

Certainly I'm not going to host some where I thought It could be the only solution for now at least. Will surely close out question.

Comment: your is reflecting the form itself but just without the additional parameters which are added to the form by running the downloadFile javascript method. Note that there are multiple versions of that method within the original page, accepting different numbers of parameters.

Comment: your _code_, it should read at the start of the last comment. Sorry - typo.